# MySQL Workbench: Using the CAST function to return date and time with error

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

For the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    OrderDate,
    CAST(OrderDate AS data(YY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS)) AS 'Order - full date and time',
    CAST(OrderDate AS data(YY:MM)) AS 'Order - year and month',
FROM orders;
```

I receive the following error message:

> "SELECT" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: '(', WITH

I am a total newbie at SQL. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a datetime column, you can format it with [MySQL string function `date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT 
    OrderDate,
    DATE_FORMAT(OrderDate, '%y:%m:%d:%H:%i:%s') AS `Order - full date and time`,
    DATE_FOMAT(OrderDate '%y:%m') AS `Order - year and month`
FROM orders;
```

`date_format()` supports a wide variety of format specifiers that you can use to adjust the output.

Answer (score 0):

If your OrderDate can is a datetime that can be cast.

you can use this query.

```
SELECT 
    OrderDate,
    DATE_FORMAT(CAST(OrderDate AS DATETIME),'%y:%m:%d:%H:%i:%s') AS 'Order - full date and time',
    DATE_FORMAT(CAST(OrderDate AS DATE),'%y:%m') AS 'Order - year and month'
FROM orders;
```

But if you have another type or format for OrderDate   you have to use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)